# Coupling small and large injectivity radii

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I'd like to know whether a manifold of constant curvature, which has large injectivity radius at many points, can have points of arbitrary small injectivity radius.

More precisely, for a point $x$ in a Riemann manifold $M$ let $\rho(x)$ denote the injectivity radius at $x$ and let $\rho(M)$ denote the infimum of all $\rho(x)$, $x\in M$.

**My question is this:** Let $R>0$ be given. Do there exist $c,\varepsilon >0$ such that for every hyperbolic surface $S$, such that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{vol}\big(\{x\in S: \rho(x)\le R\}\big)}{\mathrm{vol}(S)}<\varepsilon
$$
one has that $\rho(S)\ge c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is "no". To see this, fix $R>0,\ \varepsilon>0$. For any $n\ge2$, let $S_n$ be a compact Riemann surface of genus $n$ with Fenchel-Nielsen coordinates
$$L=\left(\frac{1}{n},\underbrace{n,\dots,n}_{3n-2}\right),$$
$$A=(\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{3n-3}).$$

The sequence $\left\{S_n\right\}_{n\ge2}$ converges to the hyperbolic plane in the sense of Benjamini-Schramm, i.e.
$$\frac{vol(\{x\in\ S_n\ :\ \rho(x)\le R\})}{vol(S_n)}\xrightarrow[]{n\to\infty}0.$$

In particular, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ big enough,
$$\frac{vol(\{x\in\ S_n\ :\ \rho(x)\le R\})}{vol(S_n)}<\varepsilon.$$
On the other hand, due to the choice of the Fenchel-Nielsen parameters, the length of the short geodesic of $S_n$ is $\frac{1}{n}$. Therefore, for any $c>0$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ big enough,
$$\rho(S_n)<c.$$

Comment: Presumably for these metrics to converge to the hyperbolic plane, you have to choose a sequence of *based* metrics, i.e., choose a specific point on each of the compact surfaces.  Could you comment more fully on how you choose the basepoints?

Comment: I don't think this answer is complete.  Fenchel-Nielsen coordinates themselves are insufficient to control the global geometry of the surface.  What could in principle happen is that shorter loops could arise (shorter than the basis elements).

Comment: I am sorry, but I think I do not understand how there could be loops shorter than any basis element. If I understood Fenchel-Nielsen coordinates properly, then in the above example the length of the shortest simple closed geodesic (not loop in general) is 1/n.  Then, by the collar Theorem the injectivity radius of a point is an (increasing) function of its distance from the closest simple short geodesic, so that any geodesic loop is longer than 1/n.

Comment: That's true, but one needs a better lower bound for the other loops than just $\frac1n$ here :-)

Comment: I see the problem now, I have to be indeed be more precise on why such a sequence should be Benjamini-Schramm convergent. I'll try and work out the details and come back to that. 
Coming back to the original question, I think  the answer is still "no". asking a uniform lower bound on the injectivity radius is equivalent to asking that the sequence of lattices which generate the surfaces is uniformly discrete. An example of a sequence of lattices which is Benjamini-Schramm convergent but not uniformly discrete can be found in "Benjamini-Schramm and spectral convergence", Example 2.10.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide some references for the terms you are using.

Comment: The notions of Benjamini-Schramm convergence, injectivity radius and uniform discreteness can be found in the aforementioned article [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.07083), as well as in [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.2961)